# Windows 10 Xbox DVR app thinks Chrome is a game

Tags: windows-10, xbox-game-dvr

When setting up the XBox game app, and the XBox DVR game bar, I must have checked the box that `Chrome is a game app`.

How do I undo that?

Every time I open Chrome, the game bar pops up.

I don't want to select "`don't show this again`", because then it'll disable it for real game apps. I just want to remove Chrome from the list.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to go to the Game Bar, and open up Settings (the gear icon), you can uncheck "Remember this as a game", and it should make Windows not remember it as a game anymore.

[image: Graphic representation showing the "Remember this as a game" being unchecked]

Comment: Also, I have a controller plugged in, and the `Open Game bar using X on a controller`, but it's not working. Any idea there?

Comment: @Pat Unfortunately, my Xbox controller isn't working at the moment so I can't test anything. It might need to be in a game already for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

In case you forgot which program is remembered as a game by the XBox Game Bar and wish to get rid of any of them, it is also possible to look up in Windows registry for stored programs.

#### A. Open Registry and Backup Branch

1. Open Registry Editor (hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then type **regedit**)
2. Go to *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore*
3. Export key (only selected branch as *gameconfigstore-backup.reg* for instance)

#### B. Delete Remembered Child

1. Go to *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore\Children*
2. Search for **MatchedExeFullPath**
3. Ensure the matching value is one of the program you want the XBox Game Bar to forget (like *..\chrome.exe*)
4. Copy key string (by right-click and *Rename*) (e.g. abcd1234-1234-1234-1234-abcd1234abcd)
5. Delete key

#### C. Delete Remembered Parent

1. Go to *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore\Parent*
2. Search for copied key at **B.4.**
3. Delete key

If you skip **B.4.** and **C.** the XBox Game Bar won't be able to remember the program as a game again (and finding out which parent doesn't have a proper child could be a rather critical task thereafter).